# Qiskit not installing properly on pyCharm CE

Tags: qiskit

I have installed qiskit through my terminal using `pip3 install qiskit`. But when I try to import all from it in my coding software, it returns a M`oduleNotFound error`:

[image]

When i try to install it in `interpreter settings`, this error message returns:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Could you give us some more details about the error/your python environment?

Comment: That's alright, I solved the problem. My default version of python was still reverting back to the original 2.7, not allowing me to download Qiskit. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, great! I am glad you have fixed it :) would you like to leave what you found as an answer to help anyone who has this question in future?